# converting escaped string to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I've a string like `'{\'stringA\': "Hello Master\'s"}'` . This should be converted in format like `{"stringA": "Hello Master's"}` . To achieve it, I wrote as below

```
input.replace("\'", "\"")
```

However, it produces output as `{"stringA": "Hello Master"s"}` - which breaks my string. Essentially, I am getting a string escaped json string (with single quotes) and I need to convert it into a proper json-string, on which I can call `json.loads` - how should I achieve it? I need to ignore single-quote(`) in my key and value in  json.

Comment: "on which I can call json.loads" do you mean you actually need to parse the string as a dict?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is not a valid Json string, because it uses single quotes. Yet it is a valid Python representation of a dictionary, so you can parse it with `literal_eval`:

```
t = '{\'stringA\': "Hello Master\'s"}'
d = ast.literal_eval(t)
print(t)
js = json.dumps(d)
print(js)
```

gives as output:

```
{'stringA': "Hello Master's"}
{"stringA": "Hello Master's"}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re, json
a = '{\'stringA\': "Hello Master\'s"}'
replace = re.findall("\'.*\':", a)
for rep in replace:
    new_val = rep.replace("\'", "\"")
     a.replace(rep, new_val)
```

It's output is '{"stringA": "Hello Master's"}'